# Объект вроде не None, а всё равно TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pyqt5, робототехника

Сори за нейминг

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtCore
import socket
import time
from mydesign import Ui_Dialog
import sys


class Robot:
    user_socket = None

    def bind(self):
        server = socket.socket(

            socket.AF_INET,
            socket.SOCK_STREAM,

        )

        server.bind(
            ("192.168.1.67", 1234)  # localhost
        )

        server.listen(5)
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            self.user_socket, address = server.accept()
            print(f"Подключено к {address}")
            break

    def stop(self):
        print("stop")
        self.user_socket.send("stop".encode("utf-8"))

    def right(self):
        print("right")
        self.user_socket.send("right".encode("utf-8"))

    def left(self):
        print("left")
        self.user_socket.send("left".encode("utf-8"))

    def back(self):
        print("back")
        self.user_socket.send("back".encode("utf-8"))

    def forward(kek):
        print("forward")
        kek.user_socket.send("forward".encode("utf-8"))


robot_dolbayeb = Robot #кодовое название проекта
robot_dolbayeb.bind(robot_dolbayeb)
print(robot_dolbayeb.user_socket)  # вот тут выводит <socket.socket fd=348, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET,
# type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.67', 1234), raddr=('192.168.1.67', 52389)>


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        print(robot_dolbayeb, robot_dolbayeb.user_socket)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(robot_dolbayeb.right(robot_dolbayeb))  # тут уже стао None :P
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(robot_dolbayeb.left(robot_dolbayeb))
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(robot_dolbayeb.back(robot_dolbayeb))
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(robot_dolbayeb.forward(robot_dolbayeb))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Когда делаю print() выводит информацию о сокете, а потом почему-то None

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вызывать методы экземпляра, его нужно создать:

Замените:

```
robot_dolbayeb = Robot #кодовое название проекта
robot_dolbayeb.bind(robot_dolbayeb)
```

на

```
robot_dolbayeb = Robot() #кодовое название проекта
robot_dolbayeb.bind()
```

и все вызовы типа

```
robot_dolbayeb.right(robot_dolbayeb)
```

на

```
robot_dolbayeb.right()
```

Comment: Он же __self__ везде вручную передаёт. Не только в `bind()`.

Comment: Там дальше по коду у него в биндингах для кнопок тоже конструкции типа `robot_dolbayeb.right(robot_dolbayeb)`. Я тоже не спец по QT, но тут же свой класс вроде как, не QT'шный.